# fetch and show selected tags as selected and remaing tags in select element

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have following three tables in mysql database.

**blog** Table
id, title, content, created, modified, active

**tag** Table
id, tag_name

**blog_tag** Table
id, tag_id, blog_id

i want to fetch data from these tables and show in form's select element.
also show selected data as selected and remaining data as select's options.
like this.

```
<select name="tags_id[]" multiple="multiple">
<option value="id" selected="selected">tag name</option>
<option value="id" selected="selected">tag name</option>
<option value="id">tag name</option>
<option value="id">tag name</option>
<option value="id" selected="selected">tag name</option>
<option value="id">tag name</option>
</select>
```

i have using php and mysql. how i can join and retrieve data for that condition and what will be loop condition.

Comment: please also provide mysql query for join tables and loop condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<option value="id" <?php echo ($tag =='tag name' ? 'selected' : '') ?>>
tag name</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the values from database, iterate of the them...and check if the id matches..select that value else echo it without adding selected key word. Hope this would give you an idea.

```
 <?php  $actualValues= // get the from database ?>

 <select name="tags_id[]" multiple="multiple">
 <?php 

  foreach($tableRows as $row){
  if($row['id']== $actualValue[$i])
   echo "<optionvalue'".$actualValue[$i]."' selected='selected'>$row['value']</option>";
   else
      echo "<optionvalue'".$actualValue[$i]."'>$actualValue['value']</option>";
 $i++;

 ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but how i can retrieve values from three tables and what will be loop condition

Comment: you can return the rows into the $actualValues using joins.. join three of them and return in this variable...

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This code fetches all the tag_names from your tag table and displays in the select box.

```
<select name="tags_id" multiple="multiple">
  <?php
  $result=mysql_query("select id,tag_name from tag");
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    if ($_GET['tags_id']==$row["id"]) {
      echo '<option selected="selected" value='.$row["id"].'>'.$row["tag_name "].'</option>';
    } else {
      echo '<option value='.$row["id"].'>'.$row["tag_name "].'</option>';
    }
  }
  ?>
</select>
```